# Understanding Vagrant and Homestead Variables

Tags: bash, vagrant, homestead

I'm reviewing the laravel homestead source code hosted in [github repository](https://github.com/laravel/homestead) and figuring out how the application works and am wondering where the variables `${1} - ${4}, ${PATH_SSL}` are declared.

I would like to better understand how laravel homestead work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are not Ruby. It's like Ruby variables, but in bash script.

For example, [here](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/blob/master/scripts/serve-laravel.sh#L5) `PATH_SSL` is being defined. Also, in the next lines it is being used (evaluate) to form another text. In Bash, you do it using evaluation syntax `${PATH_SSL}`.

```
PATH_SSL="/etc/nginx/ssl"
PATH_KEY="${PATH_SSL}/${1}.key"
PATH_CSR="${PATH_SSL}/${1}.csr"
PATH_CRT="${PATH_SSL}/${1}.crt"
```

`${1}`, `${2}`, etc. are special variables that represent arguments used while calling that script from the command line.

Comment: Thanks I now understand. I have one more question about this [line](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/blob/master/Vagrantfile#L5). I can't understand the meaning of ```confDir = $confDir ||=```

Comment: That file however is a ruby code. You can split it into 2 parts. One is double variable assignment `confDir = $confDir = "someValue"` and the second part is `someVar ||= File.expand_path("~/.homestead")` conditional asignment operator.
The first operation basically assigns a value to both variables.
The second operation assigns a value of `File.exppa...` to `someVar` only if `someVar` is false or nil.
So, if you combine those 2, you would end up with: if `$confDir` variable is not defined, set its value to `File.expand ...`, otherwise do nothing and then assign whatever to local var `confDir`.

Comment: @yaeykay, if that answers your question, consider selecting it as answer, so that your question is marked closed.

Comment: Now I get it. Thank you